# DataTables, get value of hidden cell

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

I have a DataTables Table, and I want to be able to get the value of the first td, when the tr is clicked on. I have set the visibility of this td to false.

Edit: because the two answers so far are assuming I can click on the cell I want. 
**I cannot click on the cell I need the value of.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({ 
        select: false,
        "columnDefs": [{
            className: "ID", 
            "targets":[0],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable":false
        }]
    });//End of create main table



    $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {

        cellValue =     //code to get the cell value 
        console.log(cellValue);

    });

});
```

I have seen a lot of examples using the older DataTables method, *fnGetColumnData*, but am not sure how to implement the newer *cell.data()*.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: table.cell( this ).data() ;

Comment: @NagaSaiA Doesn't that just give me the value oft he clicked on cell?

Comment: to get cell use td instead of tr and use table.cell(this).data()

Comment: @Yea.. That gets the cell I am clicking on. Not quite what I need.

Comment: Please check this updated codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/WxjNPK

Comment: use table.row( this ).data()[0]; to get invisible data

Comment: http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/kXyazm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve expected result and get hidden column data by using row(this).data()

```
  $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
     alert(table.row( this ).data()[0]); 
  });
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/kXyazm

Above mentioned code will return complete row data both hidden and visible data and mention the position of the hidden column position

Comment: So that's  a nice piece of code for retrieving the cell that I am clicking on. However, I can not click on the cell for whos value I want... The cell I want, is hidden. I would like to be able to click on a row, and get the value of the first cell.

Comment: for getting only first value , use below option 
  $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
 console.log($(this)[0].children[0].innerHTML) ;  
  });

Comment: That works, if the html is there. Because I am using the DataTable plugin to set `"visible": false', the element is not displayed. I think the only way to accomplish this is to use one of the methods provided by DataTables - I just don't know how to implement it!

Comment: Take a look at how I am implementing the table, in the JS in my original post

Comment: @blackandorangecat i have updated the answer with the changes in the coepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/kXyazm

Comment: In this example, i am fetching hidden column data - Name using row(this).data(). Hope this is helpful for you :)